# How Do I Regex Replace Captured Groups In Ansible?

Tags: regex, ansible

I have a bat file on Windows that has been transferred from Linux. It has linux paths in it and these need to be converted to Windows paths.

When there was just a single instance of the path in it I was using `win_lineinfile` like this:

```
- name: Change linux paths to windows paths in load.bat
  win_lineinfile:
    path: "{{ working_directory }}/bin/load.bat"
    backrefs: yes
    # The regex removes the quotes, replaces slashes with backslashes and sets the root as E:\ and leaves the rest of the line as is
    # "/apps/test/23.4.0.6_env1/bin/load.bat"
    # E:\apps\test\23.4.0.6_env1\bin\load.bat
    regexp: '^\"/.*/[0-9a-zA-Z-._]*(.*bat)\"(.*)'
    line: "{{ working_directory | replace ('/',backslash) }}$1$2"
  vars:
    backslash: "\\"
```

The variable `working_directory` was `E:\apps\test\23.4.0.6_env1`

The line in the load.bat looked like this:

```
"/apps/test/23.4.0.6_env1/bin/load.bat" com.stackoverflow.startup.StartApp -env env1 -log  -user %username% %LOG_DIR% %*
```

Now the `load.bat` has changed and this path is in multiple lines in the file - not just at the beginning of the line and even one instance where it is twice in a single line.

The `win_lineinfile` module can't be used as it only replaces a single line.
The `replace` module can't be used as it doesn't work on Windows.

What I have gone for is `slurp` to read the file, `set_fact` to replace the text with `regex_replace` and `win_copy` to write the file back to disk.

It looks like this:

```
- name: Read the file
  slurp:
    src: "{{ working_directory }}/bin/load.bat"
  register: loaded_file

- name: Change linux paths to windows paths in load.bat
  set_fact:
    updated_content:
      "{{ loaded_file['content'] | b64decode | regex_replace('(\\/apps)([0-9a-zA-Z-._\\/]+)', 'E:\\\\apps\\\\\\2') | regex_replace('/', '\\\\') }}"
  vars:
    backslash: "\\"

- name: Write the content back to a test file for now
  win_copy:
    content:
      "{{ updated_content }}"
    dest:
      "{{ working_directory }}/bin/load2.bat"
```

This partially works. It changes the path to `E:\apps\\test\23.4.0.6_env1\bin\load.bat`. It has that double backslash in it though: `E:\apps\\`.

It also replaces all other forward slashes to backslashes in the whole file rather than just in the second capturing group.

Normal find and replace regex works but the Ansible syntax is messing things up.

How do I do the replace of the forward slashes just in my path and not the rest of the file?

Bonus points if you can make it look nicer/clearer without so many backslashes.